# BorderLayout NORTH SOUTH CENTER panes height doesn't auto resize when changing window size

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, autoresize, border-layout

i am trying to add 2 panels one to the south and the other to the north using BorderLayout but when i try to change window width/height by dragging/maximizing window the height doesn't get resized but instead gets cut off , although the width resized just fine.
I want all the panels to get auto resized all at once while playing with the window, what am i missing?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class testss extends JFrame
{
    JPanel red = new ColorPanel(Color.red,300,300);
    JPanel grn = new ColorPanel(Color.green,100,600);
    JPanel orange = new ColorPanel(Color.ORANGE,100,50);
    JPanel blue = new ColorPanel(Color.BLUE,100,50);
    public  testss()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(10, 10) );
        blue.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        grn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        orange.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        panel.add(grn, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(blue,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.add(orange,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.getContentPane().add(panel);   
        this.setVisible(true);   
        this.pack();   
    }   


    public static void main(String[] args)   
    {   
        new testss();   
    }   
}   


class ColorPanel extends JPanel   
{   
    public ColorPanel(Color color, int W, int H)   
    {   
        this.setBackground(color);   
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(W,H));   
    }   
}
```

Comment: *"what am i missing?"* - An understanding into how `BorderLayout` works. Both the `SOUTH` and `NORTH` components will honour their preferred height. The remain space is provided to the `CENTER` position, this is how it works.  Depending on your needs, you might consider using a `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout` instead

Comment: Getting a layout manager which will honour the ratios correctly might prove to be more difficult

Comment: `I want all the panels to get auto resized` - define "auto resized"?

Comment: btw, call pack() before the setVisible()

Comment: GridLayout works just fine only thing is cells are of the same size , i need diff size  between cells